# Как увеличить шрифт во всем документе Open-Office?

Tags: open-office

Есть документ Open-Office, в котором слишком мелкий шрифт. Надо его увеличить пропорционально для всего документа (то есть для текста, для заголовков и т.д.). Например, сам текст сейчас размера 5, а надо, чтобы стал размера 7. Заголовки сейчас размера 7, а надо, чтобы стали размера 9. И так далее. Но если выделить весь текст через ctrl+A, то поле кегля становится недоступно. Однако, если выделить отдельный абзац, то поле кегля становится доступно и размер текста можно увеличить.

Как в документе Open-Office увеличить пропорционально для всего документа увеличить текст? Не делать же все это вручную, по отдельным абзацам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По абзацам точно не стоит, но вы можете настроить стили, насколько я помню. Стили заголовков, текста и так далее. Посмотрите какими стилями набраны заголовки и сам текст - и поменяйте кегль в стиле на тот который Вас устраивает.

Comment: Спасибо, так помогло. Правда, поглючило сначала, налепило лишних пустых страниц. Но потом вроде заработало.

Answer (score 1):

А если стили не настроены, то выделить всё, а затем `Формат->Текст->Увеличить кегль`, или же <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Проверено для LibreOffice-5.4.

Comment: А так не помогло. Нет там пункта "Текст" в меню "Формат".

Comment: @pepsicoca1, проверено для LibreOffice-5.4.2.2.0+ На каких-либо более старых версиях гарантировать не могу + перевод может отличаться.

Comment: У меня не  LibreOffice, а  OpenOffice 4.1.4 (AOO414m5(Build:9788)  -  Rev. 1811857 2017-10-11 20:12), то есть последняя версия. Там нет этого пункта. Скорее всего это фича LibreOffice. В OpenOffice этого нет.

Comment: И ctrl+] не работает.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, дык, понятно, раз в OOo этого нет...